# R - how to get vector of strings frequency if i have strings in matrix and their factor levels

Tags: r, vector, matrix, cluster-analysis, frequency

I have a lot of strings (several k-mers of DNA reads). It storage in R-language matrix (or array?), f.e.:

```
allKmers <- character()
allKmers <- c(allKmers,c("ACG", "CGT", "GTA", "TAC")) # V1
allKmers <- c(allKmers,c("GTA", "TAC", "ACG", "CGC")) # V2
allKmers <- c(allKmers,c("TAA", "AAT", "ATA", "TAA")) # V3
arrayKmers <- array(allKmers, dim = c(4,3), dimnames = NULL) # this is it!
```

And then i can get all unique levels from the factor:

```
levels(as.factor(arrayKmers))
[1] "AAT" "ACG" "ATA" "CGC" "CGT" "GTA" "TAA" "TAC"
```

You see? 8 levels.

And then i want to get 3 vectors with 8 values, corresponding to  frequency of meeting this levels in V1, V2 and V3, e.g.:

```
< 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1 > # V1 
< 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1 > # V2 
< 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 > # V3
```

Is there any easy way to get this vectors? May be some nice function? I can code it manually, but may be you know some better tool for that? Then i will calculate dist matrix, do clustering, blablabla.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match V1, V2 etc against the unique levels then tabulate the results.

```
uKmers <- levels(as.factor(arrayKmers))
freqKmers <- apply(arrayKmers, 2, function(x){
  tabulate(match(x, uKmers), length(uKmers))
}
)

> t(freqKmers)
[,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
[1,]    0    1    0    0    1    1    0    1
[2,]    0    1    0    1    0    1    0    1
[3,]    1    0    1    0    0    0    2    0
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one approach:

```
library(qdapTools)
mtabulate(split(t(data.frame(arrayKmers)), 1:3))

##   AAT ACG ATA CGC CGT GTA TAA TAC
## 1   0   1   0   0   1   1   0   1
## 2   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1
## 3   1   0   1   0   0   0   2   0
```